# append an element in front of li element

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular material, and I want to append the `md-fab-speed-dial` in front of an `li` element.

When I do that I get the `md-fab-speed-dial` bellow the `li` element as shown in this picture :

[image]

How can I solve this.

Demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzpZLz

## Edit :

this is how I want it to look in demo :

[image]

And this is how I want it to look in my application :

[image]

Comment: Like this?
https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/LjWPRy?editors=1010 I just moved it before the element completely

Comment: @Nick nope, that's the top, I want it just in front of the li element , check my edit

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the button using flexbox and the list using a simple display block.

You can change it if you add a class to the li that you want the button to be inline with with the code below: https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/LjWPRy?editors=1000

```
li.align-button-inline{
display:flex;
align-items: center
}
```

and then change the html like this:

```
<ul>
        <li class="adding-inline-button">Element 1 

        <md-fab-speed-dial md-open="false" md-direction="right" ng-class="md-fling">
                <md-fab-trigger>
          <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn md-mini">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </md-fab-trigger>

        <md-fab-actions>
          <md-button aria-label="twitter" class="md-fab md-raised">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/twitter.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
          <md-button aria-label="facebook" class="md-fab md-raised">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/facebook.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
          <md-button aria-label="Google hangout" class="md-fab md-raised">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/hangout.svg"></md-icon>
          </md-button>
        </md-fab-actions>
      </md-fab-speed-dial>
    </li>
```

the downside of doing this tho, is that the dot from the element in the list disappears. I don't know if this is an issue or not (as you might wanna get rid of them anyway) but if you wanna keep them, you can easily add a dot before it with either a font or a :before pseudo element.

Hope it helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzyBZW)

You're already using the `md-right` class on the speed dial element, which is trying to use flex to position it. So, you can just add these styles;

```
li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

So that the `<li>` uses flex, and vertically aligns its children in the center. You're going to want to attach these styles to a class, not the `<li>` element itself though.